# c# calling web service error: "The client certificate is Not provided. Specify a client certificate in client credentials"

Tags: c#, web-services, https, certificate

I am trying to call a web service on my server over https from my mvc3 app. I have web services located at this address:

`https:localhost/web_services/web_services.asmx`

And in my code i try to connect like this:

```
 var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
 binding.maxbuffersize = 10000;
 binding.maxbufferPoolsize = 10000; 
 binding.maxreceivedmessageSize= 10000;
 binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialsType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate


 var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https:/localhost/web_services/web_services.asmx");
 new ChannelFactory<ws_name_webreqSoap>(basicHttpsBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
 var webServices = new ws_name_webreqSoapClient(basicHttpsBinding, endpointAddress);
```

However, when this runs on the server, i get the following message:

"The client certificate is Not provided. Specify a client certificate in client credentials"

My knowledge of HTTPS and certificates is limited. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the client certificate on the ChannelFactory:

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ws_name_webreqSoap>(basicHttpsBinding, endpointAddress);
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate("CN=client.com", StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My);
var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
// ...
```